# Multiple instances of variable local to function with diferent value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a question in javascript can multiple instances of the same variable local to a function exist simulateous, each with it's own value? This might be related to the closure as a variable in a function might have a value but inside a function defined in that function might have another value?

Comment: Uhmm... NO. Would you like me to recommend a Basic Javascript Tutorial? On a side note: I'm curious what language you can have that exist in?

Comment: Do you have some code?

Comment: @gforce301 Yes i would like a recomendation of a javascript tutorial thank you. Bu i don't know a language where that exists. Is that i'm taking a course, and in a test for a class where i'm learning javascript that question appeared and i didn't know the answer.

Comment: Start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics

Comment: @epascarello  thank you for your help

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. You were supposed to read and adhere to the following before posting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking, especially links 1, 2, 5, and the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um, no, a variable can only hold a single value, and a function can only have one variable per name. You cannot have multiple instances of a variable in the same scope.

You can however have multiple instances of the "same" variable in different instances of the "same" scope. This is quite usual when calling a function:

```
function example(x) {
    console.log(x);
}
example(1);
example(2);
```

Here we have two instances of the variable `x`, holding different values (`1` and `2` respectively). Of course, here the two variables don't exist at the same time. That can happen however when we use closures, as you observed:

```
function makeLogger(x) {
    return function logger() {
        console.log(x);
    }
}
let loggers = [];
for (const i of [1, 2, 3]) {
    loggers[i] = makeLogger(i);
}
const [log1, log2, log3] = loggers;
log1();
log3();
```

In this example each of the three logger function has its own variable `x` with its own value.